# Ruby if statements 3 conditions

Tags: ruby, class, if-statement

```
puts 'guess my favorite num'
x = gets.chomp
unless x.kind_of?(Fixnum)
  puts "it's not a Numeric symbol"
  if x=="2"
    puts "Well done!"
    if x!=2 || x.is_a?(Fixnum)
      puts "Try more, dude"
    end
  end
end
```

Trying to learn ruby, but my code is not work :-( Need 3 DIFFERENT conditions for var. Where is a bug ?

Comment: `gets.chomp` never returns an actual number...

Comment: also, if a value equals the string `"2"` it will never equal the number `2`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "Guess my favorite num."
x = gets.chomp
begin
  if Integer(x) == 2
    puts "Well done!"
  else
    puts "Try more, dude."
  end
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "It's not an integer."
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Semi-contrived example, but you're probably looking for [`elsif`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures#if-elsif-else_expression):

```
puts 'enter a favorite num'
x = gets.chomp.to_i
if x == 2
  puts "you entered 2"
elsif x !=2
  puts "you did not enter 2"
end
```

Also--as @Jan Dvorak points out--the `gets` method returns a string, which you would want to convert (to integer in this case).

Another solution would be to  use a [`case`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-case) statement:

```
print 'enter a favorite num'
x = gets.chomp.to_i
case x
when 2
  puts "you entered 2"
else
  puts "you did not enter 2"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You did probably mean something like that:

```
loop do
  puts 'guess my favorite num'
  x = gets.chomp
  case x
  when /\D/
    puts "it's not a Numeric symbol"
  when "2"
    puts "Well done!"
    break
  else
    puts "Try more, dude"
  end
end
```